# Default child control for custom UI5 Control SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5, custom-controls

How can i make (Text Field + three buttons) as default child controls for my custom ui5 control.Whenever my custom control loads, it should render (text field +  three buttons) inside my custom control by default.

Regards,
Karthik S

Comment: Can you please share the code and place where you face the error ?

Comment: I checked this blog.                                                                                    (https://blogs.sap.com/2016/07/18/how-to-create-a-custom-ui5-control/comment-page-1/#comment-424051). There they added the child controls to their Custom Control as aggregation in the xml view. But my requirement is like whenever my Custom control loads, it should render TextField + buttons as child controls by default. Is there any possibility for my requirement.

Comment: You can remove from aggregation and keep render the buttons.

Comment: Can you explain me with any samples? Because I want to arrange Text field at the top and three buttons at the bottom(buttons arranged horizontally).

Comment: Using (--oRm.write("<button>")  oRm.writeEscaped("Button 3")--)  I can create buttons at runtime in renderer fucntion. But how do i attach event for button which is generating at runtime at reneder function?

Answer (score 0):

**in events**:  `onholdevent": {},`

**in agrredation:**

```
"button": {
 type: "sap.m.Button",
 multiple: false
},
```

**in onIt**:

```
this.setAggregation("button", new sap.m.Button({
    text: "On Press",
    press: function() {
        that.fireOnholdevent(this);
    }
}));
```

**in render** : `oControl.getAggregation("button");`

main thing is the this refrence , through 'this' you can get in controller which button is clicked .In the view just give the event name and refrence it in controller.

Comment: its  aggregation